# How can I interpret escape sequences in a multiline scala string?

Tags: scala, escaping, multiline, string-interpolation

In a nutshell:

```
"""I want to be able to
  |have the convenient formatting of a multiline string,
  |while using inline escape sequences\r\r\b\\
  |
  |How can this be done?""".stripMargin
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two options that I can think of:

1. You can use `StringContext.treatEscapes` directly:

   ```
   StringContext.treatEscapes("""I want to be able to
           |have the convenient formatting of a multiline string,
           |while using inline escape sequences\r\r\b\\
           |
           |How can this be done?""".stripMargin)
   ```
2. If the variable substitution feature of the "simple interpolator" (`s`) isn't disruptive to your needs, then try combining [string interpolation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) (which converts escaped characters) with `"""`-quotes (which doesn't escape ...):

   ```
   println("""he\\lo\nworld""")
   println(s"""he\\lo\nworld""")
   ```

   outputs

   ```
   he\\lo\nworld
   he\lo
   world
   ```

   For details, see the [relevant SIP](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/string-interpolation.html) and [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13260864/1448212).

Comment: Use `StringContext.processEscapes` as of Scala 2.13

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers - what about this idea?

```
s"""I want to be able to
  |have the convenient formatting of a multiline string,
  |while using inline escape sequences${"\r\r\b\"}\
  |
  |How can this be done?""".stripMargin
```

The only thing that won't work that way is the `\` at the end of the line.
In my example, you embed the escaped characters as a normal string, and then use string interpolation to insert them. (Mind the `s` before the opening triple quotes.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a convenient example hidden in the standard library.  It's easy to tweak in a couple of ways to add standard processing.  It's not obvious how embedded `\r` is intended, however, so `caveat interpolator`.

Update: for the record, the hard part was forgetting the sequence arg `_*`. Because it's Any*, there's no type error; the underlying interpolator just throws an error that the parts don't match the args.

Update: fixed underscore star so it doesn't italicize.

Example:

```
import reflect.internal.util.StripMarginInterpolator

object Test extends App {

  trait ZipMarginator extends StripMarginInterpolator {
    def zm(args: Any*): String = StringContext treatEscapes sm(args: _*)
  }
  implicit class ZipMarginOps(val stringContext: StringContext) extends ZipMarginator
  val sample =
zm"""I want to be able to
    |have the convenient formatting of a multiline string,
    |while using inline escape sequences
    |like\t\ttabs and \\Program Files\\backslashes.
    |
    |How can this be done?"""
  Console println sample

  implicit class ZipMarginOps2(val stringContext: StringContext) extends SStripMarginInterpolator {
    def sz(args: Any*): String = ssm(args: _*)
  }
  Console println sz"""
    |Another\t\texample."""
  Console println sz"""
    |Another\r\tex\nample.
    |Huh?"""

}
```

Here is the StripMargin..or with name changes to protect one's sanity, note the caveat about `raw`:

```
trait SStripMarginInterpolator {
  def stringContext: StringContext

  /**
   * A safe combination of [[scala.collection.immutable.StringLike#stripMargin]]
   * and [[scala.StringContext#raw]].
   *
   * The margin of each line is defined by whitespace leading up to a '|' character.
   * This margin is stripped '''before''' the arguments are interpolated into to string.
   *
   * String escape sequences are '''not''' processed; this interpolater is designed to
   * be used with triple quoted Strings.
   *
   * {{{
   * scala> val foo = "f|o|o"
   * foo: String = f|o|o
   * scala> sm"""|${foo}
   *             |"""
   * res0: String =
   * "f|o|o
   * "
   * }}}
   */
  final def ssm(args: Any*): String = {
    def isLineBreak(c: Char) = c == '\n' || c == '\f' // compatible with StringLike#isLineBreak
    def stripTrailingPart(s: String) = {
      val (pre, post) = s.span(c => !isLineBreak(c))
      pre + post.stripMargin
    }
    val stripped: List[String] = stringContext.parts.toList match {
      case head :: tail => head.stripMargin :: (tail map stripTrailingPart)
      case Nil => Nil
    }
    new StringContext(stripped: _*).s(args: _*)  // <= MODIFIED for s instead of raw
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, ty.  If I read that right, it automates the stringMargin call, while otherwise doing exactly what the `s` interpolator does.  May still be a problem if the original text shouldn't be subjected to variable substitution.

Comment: Should `def zm(args: Any*): String = StringContext treatEscapes sm(args: _*)` be instead `def zm(args: Any*): String = StringContext treatEscapes ssm(args: _*)` [s/sm/ssm]?

Comment: @RichardSitze  The first example uses the inherited sm method from reflect.internal and calls treatEsc like your option 1; the second uses the copy/pasted version and passes the stripped part to standard s.  But see the update, ha, it drove me temporarily insane to figure out that error.  And now I see that SO has converted _* to emphasis markup. So I don't see anything straight today.