# Replace \r\n with \n

Tags: scala, carriage-return

This does not work:

```
scala> """one\r\ntwo\r\nthree\r\nfour""".replace("\r\n", "\n")
res1: String = one\r\ntwo\r\nthree\r\nfour
```

How to do that in Scala?

Is there a more idiomatic way of doing that, instead of using replace?

Comment: `"""\r\n"""` is very different from `"\r\n"`.

Comment: @n.m. Yepp, I just realized about it. I'll accept that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `"""` quotes does not expand escape sequences. Three different approaches:

1. Use single `"` quotes in order to treat escape sequences correctly: `"one\r\ntwo"`;
2. Use the `s` string interpolator, be careful following this approach cause this could lead to unexpected replacements: `s"""one\r\ntwo"""`;
3. Call [`treatEscapes`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/StringContext$.html#treatEscapes(str:String):String) directly to expands escape sequences in your string: `StringContext.treatEscapes("""one\r\ntwo""")`.

Refer also to [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868655/how-can-i-interpret-escape-sequences-in-a-multiline-scala-string).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
"""one\r\ntwo\r\nthree\r\nfour""".replace("\\r\\n", "\n")
```

`\` is treated as `escape` charater within string, so you need to tell the `compiler` that its not a `escape` character but a `string`.