# How does $ symbol working when selecting columns from DataFrame?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

when we try to select Columns from DataFrame, one can use `$"columnname"` or `col("columnname")` or just `"columnname"`.

My question is how `$ symbol`[which returns ColumnName] is working, i can understand i need to `import sqlContext.implicits._` to use $ symbol on `df.select`

I dont see `$ method` on `SQLImplicits` class as well. I can see one method with the name `symbolToColumn(scala.Symbol s)`.

Can someone explain more on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String interpolation in Scala 2.10 - How to interpolate a String variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260864/string-interpolation-in-scala-2-10-how-to-interpolate-a-string-variable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It comes from [`StringToColumn`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits$StringToColumn) implicit inner class in `SQLImplicits` (which is implemented by [the `implicits` object](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$implicits$)).

`StringContext` is the way that `f` / `s` and other string interpolators are written in Scala.

Comment: Ha, so they are overloading the string interpolation behavior? How does Spark determine if you want string interpolation vs column selection?

Comment: If you wanted string interpolation you would use `s` / `f` and Scala would pull in the default string interpolator instead.

Comment: Ah, I see know. Thanks!

Comment: The *really* simple answer is that `foo"bla"` is syntactic sugar for `StringContext.foo("bla")`, and so you can "invent" your own string literal semantics just by providing a `StringContext.foo` method.